get running total of transactions by one date and then determine if they are current by another date
thanks in advance for any help.
I am trying to generate a running total of transactions by the transaction date. Then for each total, seeing if the transactions that make up that total are passed due
for example i'm trying to get the "current?" field (it doesn't have to be the text below it can be a date or amount):



trans_date
due_date
transaction_amt
running total
current?




14-OCT-14
05-JAN-15
141.43
141.43
Yes - it is Oct and isn't due until Jan


12-NOV-14
05-JAN-15
122.29
263.72
Yes - it is Nov and isn't due until Jan


21-NOV-14
05-JAN-15
-167.72
96
yes - the 96 is for charges due in Jan


26-NOV-14
05-JAN-15
-96
0
Yes - total = 0 so current


14-DEC-14
05-JAN-15
152.1
152.1
Yes - customer owes 152 but not until Jan 5th


14-DEC-14
05-JAN-15
-51
101.1
Yes - customer owes 101 but not until Jan 5th


13-JAN-15
04-FEB-15
-76
25.1
No - the 25.1 was due on Jan 5 and it is 13th


14-JAN-15
04-FEB-15
167.88
192.98
no - still owes 25.1 from Jan 5


14-JAN-15
04-FEB-15
-51
141.98
Yes -51 took care of the 25.1 and 141 due FEB



very odd situation i know so let me know if any additional data would be helpful
i tried using the analytics functions to get the running total for transactions (that is working)
but i haven't been able to figure out how to basically take the running total and go back up the sort to see what the max (most recent) due date would be for that amount of money.
I just need to know when the account is current if that helps. hoping to get a sql query or pointed in the right direction to what that query should look like.
adding a copy of one of the queries i tried i was trying to do something around the idea of... if i group by due dt and the running total is greater than the total owed for that particular due date... it must not be current
    select   transacton_date, due_dt,  
 trans_amt, 
sum(trans_amt) over (order by due_Dt) as running_total, 
sum(trans_amt) over (order by transacton_date rows unbounded preceding ) as run_tot_by_freeze
,sum(trans_amt) over (partition by due_dt order by due_Dt) as tot_for_the_due
from (
  select  transacton_date,    sum(trans_amt) trans_amt, due_dt
  from ( 
  select  
                       transacton_date, 
                        fin.trans_amt,
                      
                        case 
                        when due_dt is null then transacton_date else due_dt end as due_dt
   FROM
                       act  act inner join act_type st on st.act_type_cd = act.act_type_cd
                       inner join fin fin on fin.act_id = act.act_id AND fin.transacton_date IS NOT NULL
                       left outer join bill  bill on bill.bill_id = fin.bill_id 
                    WHERE
                        acct_id = '12340000' 
                       
                        )
                        group by 
                transacton_date,
                ft_type_flg,
                due_dt
                 HAVING  SUM(transacton_date) != 0
                   order by transacton_date
         )
         order by transacton_date


It would be helpful to have the text of the query you're trying (and is failing) to do. I have a feeling either a CTE or analytic window functions will be the key to what you're doing

"transaction_date" is DATE datatype, so what is the meaning of SUM(transacton_date) != 0

Hi you can try something like this,
--Untested
select trans_date,  due_date,   transaction_amt,    running total,
case WHEN DATEDIFF(day,due_date, trans_date) < 0 
THEN to_char(running_total) || "Amount is due"
ELSE "Not due" END
FROM table_data;


thanks i think that would get me the running total with the text. but the part i am most interested in is how do i figure out that after the $76 payment... the 25.1 that is left is from the charge two entries prior
so this 25.10 is unpaid from....
13-JAN-15 04-FEB-15 -76 25.1 No - the 25.1 was due on Jan 5 and it is 13th
this one
14-DEC-14 05-JAN-15 152.1 152.1 Yes - customer owes 152 but not until Jan 5th

sorry for all the edits new to stack overflow
thanks i think that would get me the running total with the text. but the part i am most interested in is how do i figure out that after the $76 payment... the 25.1 that is left is from the charge two entries prior
so this 25.10
13-JAN-15 04-FEB-15 -76 25.1
is unpaid from....this one
14-DEC-14 05-JAN-15 152.1 152.1

With a combined of analytical and recursive CTE you may approach your goal, but still to be tested on more data, some CASE may probably be simplified by combining LEAST/GREATEST, but as is may be easier to debug:
with data(trans_date, due_date, transaction_amt, running_total, comm) as (
    select date '2014-10-14', date '2015-01-05', 141.43, 141.43, 'Yes - it is Oct and isn''t due until Jan' union all
    select date '2014-11-12', date '2015-01-05', 122.29, 263.72, 'Yes - it is Nov and isn''t due until Jan' union all
    select date '2014-11-21', date '2015-01-05', -167.72, 96, 'yes - the 96 is for charges due in Jan' union all
    select date '2014-11-26', date '2015-01-05', -96, 0, 'Yes - total = 0 so current' union all
    select date '2014-12-14', date '2015-01-05', 152.1, 152.1, 'Yes - customer owes 152 but not until Jan 5th' union all
    select date '2014-12-14', date '2015-01-05', -51, 101.1, 'Yes - customer owes 101 but not until Jan 5th' union all
    select date '2015-01-13', date '2015-02-04', -76, 25.1, 'No - the 25.1 was due on Jan 5 and it is 13th' union all
    select date '2015-01-14', date '2015-02-04', 167.88, 192.98, 'no - still owes 25.1 from Jan 5' union all
    select date '2015-01-14', date '2015-02-04', -51, 141.98, 'Yes -51 took care of the 25.1 and 141 due FEB'
),
rdata as (
    select 
        row_number() over(order by trans_date) as rn,
        trans_date, due_date, transaction_amt, running_total, comm,
        lag(due_date) over(order by trans_date) as prev_due_date,
        case when
            trans_date > lag(due_date) over(order by trans_date) and running_total > 0 then 'no'
            else 'yes'
        end as calc,
        case when
            trans_date > lag(due_date) over(order by trans_date) and running_total > 0 then running_total
            else 0
        end as past_due     
    from data
),
cte(rn, trans_date, due_date, transaction_amt, running_total, comm, prev_due_date, calc, past_due) as (
    select * from rdata
    where rn = 1
    
    union all
    
    select d.rn, d.trans_date, d.due_date, d.transaction_amt, d.running_total, d.comm, d.prev_due_date,
        case c.calc 
        when 'yes' then 
            case when
                d.trans_date > d.prev_due_date and d.running_total > 0 then 'no'
                else 'yes'
            end 
        else
            case when d.running_total > c.running_total then 'no'
            else 
                case when -d.transaction_amt > c.past_due then 'yes'
                else 'no' end
            end
        end,
        case c.calc 
        when 'yes' then 
            case when
                d.trans_date > d.prev_due_date and d.running_total > 0 then d.running_total
                else 0
            end 
        else
            case when d.running_total > c.running_total then c.past_due
            else 
                case when -d.transaction_amt > c.past_due then 0
                else c.past_due + d.transaction_amt
                end
            end
        end
    from 
    cte c
    join rdata d on d.rn = c.rn + 1
)
select * from cte
;

(I am on 23c, so I skipped the FROM DUAL you may have to add...)

Tryed to create some sample data for the query you've provided and, if I got it right, it looks like you could  use Oracle's MODEL clause to get it done. It is quite usefull in cases of interrows/intercolumns operations.
First, some sample data....
WITH     --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    act AS
        ( Select '12340000' "ACCT_ID", 'TEST_ACCOUNT' "ACCT_NAME", 'TYPE_1' "ACCT_TYPE_CD" From Dual 
        ), 
    act_type AS
        ( Select 'TYPE_1' "ACCT_TYPE_CD" From Dual 
        ),
    fin ( ACCT_ID, TRANS_DATE, DUE_DATE, TRANS_AMT, BILL_ID ) AS
        ( Select '12340000', DATE '2014-10-14', DATE '2015-01-05',  141.43, 111  From Dual Union All
          Select '12340000', DATE '2014-11-12', DATE '2015-01-05',  122.29, 111  From Dual Union All
          Select '12340000', DATE '2014-11-21', DATE '2015-01-05', -167.72, 111  From Dual Union All
          Select '12340000', DATE '2014-11-26', DATE '2015-01-05',  -96.00, 111  From Dual Union All
          Select '12340000', DATE '2014-12-14', DATE '2015-01-05',  152.10, 111  From Dual Union All
          Select '12340000', DATE '2014-12-14', DATE '2015-01-05',  -51.00, 111  From Dual Union All
          Select '12340000', DATE '2015-01-13', DATE '2015-02-04',  -76.00, 111  From Dual Union All
          Select '12340000', DATE '2015-01-14', DATE '2015-02-04',  167.88, 111  From Dual Union All
          Select '12340000', DATE '2015-01-14', DATE '2015-02-04',  -51.00, 111  From Dual 
        ),
    bill AS
        ( Select 111 "BILL_ID" From Dual Union All
          Select 222 From Dual
        )

... for modeling purposes added RN (row number) column to Dimension By and STARTING_DUE_DATE to track the transactions per due dates - checked them using Case expressions and get IS_CURRENT column as YES/NO
--    S Q L :
SELECT      TRANS_DATE, DUE_DATE, TRANS_AMT, R_TOTAL, IS_CURRENT
FROM    (   Select      Sum(1) Over(Partition By act.ACCT_ID, st.ACCT_TYPE_CD, bill.BILL_ID 
                                    Order By TRANS_DATE, DUE_DATE, TRANS_AMT Desc Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) "RN",
                        act.ACCT_ID, st.ACCT_TYPE_CD, bill.BILL_ID, fin.TRANS_DATE, fin.TRANS_AMT,
                        Case When fin.DUE_DATE Is Null Then fin.TRANS_DATE Else fin.DUE_DATE End "DUE_DATE",
                        Sum(fin.TRANS_AMT) Over (Partition By act.ACCT_ID, st.ACCT_TYPE_CD, bill.BILL_ID
                                                 Order By fin.DUE_DATE Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) "R_TOTAL",
                        Cast('' As VarChar2(64)) "IS_CURRENT"
            From        act   
            Inner Join  act_type st ON(st.ACCT_TYPE_CD = act.ACCT_TYPE_CD)
            Inner Join  fin  ON(fin.ACCT_ID = act.ACCT_ID And 
                        fin.TRANS_DATE Is Not Null)
            Left  Join  bill ON(bill.BILL_ID = fin.BILL_ID) 
            Where         act.ACCT_ID = '12340000' 
            Order By      TRANS_DATE
        )
        MODEL   Partition By  ( ACCT_ID, ACCT_TYPE_CD, BILL_ID )
                Dimension By  ( RN )
                Measures      ( TRANS_DATE, DUE_DATE, TRANS_AMT, R_TOTAL, IS_CURRENT, Cast(Null As DATE) "STARTING_DUE_DATE" )
        RULES   ( STARTING_DUE_DATE[ANY] = Nvl(Case  When R_TOTAL[CV()] <= 0  OR R_TOTAL[CV() - 1] = 0 Then DUE_DATE[CV()]
                                                     When R_TOTAL[CV()] >  0 Then Max(DUE_DATE)[RN < CV()] 
                                               End, DUE_DATE[CV()]),
                  IS_CURRENT[ANY] = Case When ( R_TOTAL[CV() - 1] > 0 And 
                                                STARTING_DUE_DATE[CV() - 1] = DUE_DATE[CV()] And 
                                                TRANS_DATE[CV()] <= DUE_DATE[CV()]
                                              ) 
                                              OR CV(RN) = 1
                                              OR ( R_TOTAL[CV() - 1] = 0 And TRANS_DATE[CV()] <= DUE_DATE[CV()] )
                                         Then 'YES'
                                         When R_TOTAL[CV()] = 0 And TRANS_DATE[CV()] <= DUE_DATE[CV()] Then 'YES'
                                   Else 'NO' End 
                )

/*    R e s u l t : 
TRANS_DATE DUE_DATE  TRANS_AMT    R_TOTAL IS_CURRENT    
---------- -------- ---------- ---------- --------------
14.10.14   05.01.15     141,43     141,43 YES           
12.11.14   05.01.15     122,29     263,72 YES           
21.11.14   05.01.15    -167,72         96 YES           
26.11.14   05.01.15        -96          0 YES           
14.12.14   05.01.15      152,1      152,1 YES           
14.12.14   05.01.15        -51      101,1 YES           
13.01.15   04.02.15        -76       25,1 NO            
14.01.15   04.02.15     167,88     192,98 NO            
14.01.15   04.02.15        -51     141,98 YES          */

NOTE:
I did the groupings by guessing from your code and it is very likely that you should adjust it to fit your actual context. The same is with the Case expressions conditions - they should be checked and adjusted if needed - it works with this sample data...

You have to calculate the dues for each date and then if running total is greater than dues then NO else YES.
WITH --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
act AS
 (Select '12340000' "ACCT_ID",
         'TEST_ACCOUNT' "ACCT_NAME",
         'TYPE_1' "ACCT_TYPE_CD"
    From Dual),
act_type AS
 (Select 'TYPE_1' "ACCT_TYPE_CD" From Dual),
fin(ACCT_ID,
TRANS_DATE,
DUE_DATE,
TRANS_AMT,
BILL_ID) AS
 (Select '12340000', DATE '2014-10-14', DATE '2015-01-05', 141.43, 111
    From Dual
  Union All
  Select '12340000', DATE '2014-11-12', DATE '2015-01-05', 122.29, 111
    From Dual
  Union All
  Select '12340000', DATE '2014-11-21', DATE '2015-01-05', -167.72, 111
    From Dual
  Union All
  Select '12340000', DATE '2014-11-26', DATE '2015-01-05', -96.00, 111
    From Dual
  Union All
  Select '12340000', DATE '2014-12-14', DATE '2015-01-05', 152.10, 111
    From Dual
  Union All
  Select '12340000', DATE '2014-12-14', DATE '2015-01-05', -51.00, 111
    From Dual
  Union All
  Select '12340000', DATE '2015-01-13', DATE '2015-02-04', +76.00, 111
    From Dual
  Union All
  Select '12340000', DATE '2015-01-14', DATE '2015-02-04', 167.88, 111
    From Dual
  Union All
  Select '12340000', DATE '2015-01-14', DATE '2015-02-04', -51.00, 111
    From Dual
  union all
  Select '12340000', DATE '2015-01-14', DATE '2015-02-04', -76.00, 111
    From Dual),
bill AS
 (Select 111 "BILL_ID" From Dual Union All Select 222 From Dual)
SELECT TRANS_DATE,
       DUE_DATE,
       TRANS_AMT,
       R_TOTAL,
       case
         when r_total > dues then
          'No'
         else
          'yes'
       end IS_CURRENT
  FROM (Select Sum(1) Over(Partition By act.ACCT_ID, st.ACCT_TYPE_CD, bill.BILL_ID Order By TRANS_DATE, DUE_DATE, TRANS_AMT Desc Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) "RN",
               act.ACCT_ID,
               st.ACCT_TYPE_CD,
               bill.BILL_ID,
               fin.TRANS_DATE,
               fin.TRANS_AMT,
               Case
                 When fin.DUE_DATE Is Null Then
                  fin.TRANS_DATE
                 Else
                  fin.DUE_DATE
               End "DUE_DATE",
               Sum(fin.TRANS_AMT) Over(Partition By act.ACCT_ID, st.ACCT_TYPE_CD, bill.BILL_ID Order By fin.DUE_DATE Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) "R_TOTAL",
               
               Sum(decode(sign(TRANS_AMT), -1, 0, trans_amt)) Over(Partition By act.ACCT_ID, st.ACCT_TYPE_CD, bill.BILL_ID, fin.due_Date Order By fin.DUE_DATE Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) "DUES",
               
               Sum(decode(sign(TRANS_AMT), 1, 0, trans_amt)) Over(Partition By act.ACCT_ID, st.ACCT_TYPE_CD, bill.BILL_ID, fin.due_Date Order By fin.DUE_DATE Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) payments,
               Cast('' As VarChar2(64)) "IS_CURRENT"
          From act
         Inner Join act_type st
            ON (st.ACCT_TYPE_CD = act.ACCT_TYPE_CD)
         Inner Join fin
            ON (fin.ACCT_ID = act.ACCT_ID And fin.TRANS_DATE Is Not Null)
          Left Join bill
            ON (bill.BILL_ID = fin.BILL_ID)
         Where act.ACCT_ID = '12340000'
         Order By TRANS_DATE)

